# Invoke all methods on a Scala object using reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Given the following object

```scala
object functions {

  type MyOutput = String

  def f1: MyOutput = "res1"

  def f2: MyOutput = "res2"

  def f3(foo: String): Boolean = foo.equals("bar")

  def f4(in:String): MyOutput = in+"res4"
}
```

Is it possible to call all methods on this object, which the returned type is of MyOutput type?

Currenly I tried to use reflection for this, but had no luck with it.

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val instanceMirror = m.reflect(typeOf[functions.type])
val classSymbol = m.classSymbol(functions.getClass)
val methods = classSymbol.info.members.filter(_.isMethod)
methods.foreach({
  method =>
    if (method.info.resultType.toString.contains("MyOutput")) {
      println(method.name.toString)
      val methodm = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(method.asMethod)
      methodm()
    }
})
```

This is the error
`scala.ScalaReflectionException: expected a member of class UniqueSingleType, you provided method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val instanceMirror = m.reflect(functions)
```

should be instead of

```
val instanceMirror = m.reflect(typeOf[functions.type])
```

This was the mistake because it's `functions` that is an instance, not `typeOf[functions.type]` (which is `UniqueSingleType` as written in the error).

Also there can be some improvements.

```
val classSymbol = m.classSymbol(functions.getClass)
val methods = classSymbol.info.members.filter(_.isMethod)
```

can be now replaced with

```
val methods = typeOf[functions.type].decls.toList.filter(_.isMethod)
```

since you know the object `functions` at compile time (so you don't need `.classSymbol`) and you're interested in the object methods rather than methods of its parents (so this is `.decls` rather than `.members`).

It's better to replace

```
method.info.resultType.toString.contains("MyOutput")
```

with

```
method.info.resultType =:= typeOf[String]
```

(aka `method.info.resultType =:= typeOf[functions.MyOutput]`) in order not to rely on a work with raw strings.

In `methodm()` you should provide arguments for the method:

```
methodm(...here...)
```